# Exclusive checkboxes in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement the following functionality in Ionic. When select type 3 I want to be able to unselect type 1 and type 2. And when I select any of the Type 1 or Type 2 I want to unselect Type 3. Also, I want to be able to select Type 1 and Type 2 together. The exclusive groups are (Type1 and Type2) and (Type3). It works when I select type 3 it unchecks type 1 and type 2, but when I select type 2 with Type 3 selected, it doesn't uncheck type 3. I read that this has something to do with updating view after the scope was updated, and I tried to use $scope.apply() but this didn't work for me. Is there a better way to implement this type of functionality.

[image]

```
$scope.setType = function (type) {
    if (type == "1") {
        $scope.type1 = true;
        $scope.type3 = false;
    }
    else if (type == "2") {
        $scope.type2 = true;
        $scope.type3 = false;
    }
    else {
        $scope.type3 = true;         
        $scope.type1 = false;
        $scope.type2 = false;
    }
};
```

These are the HTML checkboxes:

```
<div class="col">
      <ion-item class="nopadding">
          <ion-checkbox type="checkbox" ng-checked="type1" ng-click="setType('1')" value="type1"><b>Type 1</b></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
</div>
<div class="col">
      <ion-item class="nopadding">
          <ion-checkbox type="checkbox" ng-checked="type2" ng-click="setType('2')" value="type1"><b>Type 2</b></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
</div>
<div class="col">
      <ion-item class="nopadding">
          <ion-checkbox type="checkbox" ng-checked="type3" ng-click="setType('3')" value="type1"><b>Type 3</b></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Removed `Ionic2` tag... this is not an `Ionic2` question.

Comment: I tested it and it's working for me.

Comment: The logic is alright, but the view (UI) doesn't update